# How to redirect old domain https to new domain https in IIS 7

Tags: ssl, redirect, https, url-rewriting, iis-7

How can I redirect my old domains **https** address to new domains **https** address in **IIS7**?

Example;

- Old domain -> https://domain1.com (running on port: 443)
- new domain   -> https://domain2.com

i tried rewrite url rules but i'm not expert on this, i failed.
for my old domain http, it worked. 
But on https, it doesnt work.

Thank you.